# How to append a string to a Laravel 5.1 select menu option value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to append a string to the option values of a Laravel select menu.

**Controller:**

```
$anytimeMinutesList = Models\Tariff::has('deals')->where('anytime_minutes', '>', '0')
                     ->groupBy('anytime_minutes')->orderBy('anytime_minutes', 'asc')
                     ->lists('anytime_minutes', 'anytime_minutes');
$anytimeMinutesList->prepend('No minutes', '0');
$anytimeMinutesList->prepend('Any minutes', '');
```

**View:**

```
{!! Form::select('anytime_minutes', $anytimeMinutesList, Input::get('anytime_minutes'), 
 ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Please check [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld7Zl.jpg)

I would like to be able add the string ' minutes' to each of the select menu's option values so that they read:

- 200 minutes
- 250 minutes
- 300 minutes

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a simple [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) here:

```
{!! Form::select('anytime_minutes',
  array_map(function($val){
    return $val . ' minutes';
  }, $anytimeMinutesList),
  Input::get('anytime_minutes'),
  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. There were a few issues with the code. However, I have managed to get the following to produce the required output:

```
{!! Form::select('anytime_minutes',
    array_map(function($val) { 
        return $val . ' minutes';
    }, $anytimeMinutesList->toArray())) !!}
```